# error on attribute creation

Tags: magento-1.8

When creating an attribute I get this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Zend_Validate_InArray::setHaystack() must be an array, null given, called in   ....lib/Zend/Validate/InArray.php on line 96 and defined  in ..../lib/Zend/Validate/InArray.php on line 122
```

Can anyone advise why this is, I'm creating an attribute as normal, compilation off and cache cleared.

Comment: Having same issue - we have a lot of extensions that could be causing this. Will try to update once I have figured it out but this has prevented us from creating new attributes.

Comment: That would be great, haven't sorted this satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a problem with the validator of Input Types.

That is because `Mage::getStoreConfig('general/validator_data/input_types');` is returning null.

The definition of `general/validator_data/input_types` comes from `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/etc/config.xml` but an entry on the database table `core_config_data` overrides it.

Therefore, the solution is to delete the entry that specifies the 'general' path `DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path="general";`

Comment: thanks for commenting. This solution does not work, I also found it on SO but it does not work here unfortunately. I haven't been able to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.
I have deleted the general entry from my core_config_db and it is working fine for me.

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path="general";

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I had also tried this, (should have put that in the question - sorry). It didn't help sadly.